# How to capture a colored spawned process output and send to the browser via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, linux, spawn, ansi-colors

I know there have been variations on this question, but none seem to cover this particular problem.

I am spawning a child process and attempting to send the output to the browser. The issue is the ansi coloring is not making it to the output.

I've imported ansi-to-html to render the ansi output if I receive it, but my spawned child is not preserving the output.

```
  const process = spawn(
    'bash',
   [
      '-ic',
      '<command I am running>'
   ],
    );

  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    self.terminalOutput += convert.toHtml(`${data}`);

  });

  process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    self.terminalOutput += convert.toHtml(`${data}`);
  });

  process.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    self.terminalOutput += convert.toHtml(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
  });
```

Comment: Most tools refuses to output color codes if not running on an tty (or pty), verify whether the output containing color codes. If not, try to use pty or check if you can force the command output color codes even not on an tty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I found an answer here. `` `${data}` `` was implicitly converting the the data returned from the spawned process (I believe by doing type conversion implicitly calling `toString()` but I could be wrong here).

So to correctly pass the data to ansi-to-html, you must just pass it directly

```
  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    self.terminalOutput += convert.toHtml(data);
  });

  process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    self.terminalOutput += convert.toHtml(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me setting the [environment variable `FORCE_COLOR=1`](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/127#issuecomment-392249836) results in the data including ansi format string.